# Taylor series for $\sin^5 x$ at zero

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to obtain the Taylor series for $f=\sin^5 x$ at the point $\alpha = 0$, by using the known Taylor series of $\sin x$, then taking its $5$th power, as such $$\Bigl(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+ \cdots \Bigl)^5.$$

Now all that needs to be done, is to calculate the coefficient of each term individually. This doesn't seems like a good solution, and I feel like I'm really misunderstanding the point of Taylor series at this point.

Anyway, a bigger confusion I have, is that if you were to start calculating the derivatives of $\sin^5(x)$, it would not really yield anything meaningful. For example ( the first derivative ) $$f^{(1)} = 5\sin^4x\cdot \cos x.$$

So $f^{(1)}(\alpha) = 0$ when $\alpha = 0$, and so the first term is just $\frac{0}{1!}\cdot(x-\alpha)^1=0$. The 2nd and third terms are $0$, as the corresponding derivatives are $0$ at $\alpha = 0$. This is not reflected in the actual series, which has non-zero terms in their place.

If we want to find the $n$th power of a known Taylor series, what are the practical steps involved?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, $f(x) = \sin^5 x$ does not have nonzero term until $x^5$. Both methods will agree. If you differentiate and obtain $f^{(5)}(0)/5!$ you should obtain that it equals 1, in line with the first approach. Note in the first approach that the first nonzero term in power series will be $x^5$.

Comment: The problem looks messy, but I think the least-messy solution would be to use the fact that $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

Comment: The simplest (comparatively) would probably be to linearise $\sin^5x$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your method will work but is rather tedious. I'd much rather turn multiplication into addition using Chebyshev's formula:
$$
\sin^5(x) =\frac{1}{16}(10 \sin(x) - 5 \sin(3 x) + \sin(5 x));
$$knowing the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$, you can get the others by direct substitution and then add up the coefficients.

Comment: You beat me to it :) Anyway, I found that this yields $\sin^5(x) = \dfrac{5}{16} \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}(5^{2n} -3^{2n+1} + 2)$. The $n=0$ and $n=1$ terms vanish which means the series starts from an $x^5$ term, as expected... so hopefully I haven't made any algebraic error.

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo, I was too lazy to actually compute the terms :)

Answer (score 2):

An accurate answer is as follows.

1. The Faa di Bruno formula can be described in terms of partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})$ by
   \begin{equation}\label{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial}
   \frac{\textrm{d}^n}{\textrm{d} x^n}f\circ h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf^{(k)}(h(x)) B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(x),h''(x),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr).
   \end{equation}
2. The partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$ satisfy
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin-eq}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\cos x,\dotsc, \cos\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k\cos^kx}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{(2\cos x)^\ell}
   \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{n\pi}2\biggr]
   \end{multline}
   and
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin=ans}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(\cos x,-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\dotsc, \sin\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k\sin^{k}x}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac1{(2\sin x)^{\ell}}
   \sum_{q=0}^\ell(-1)^q\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{(n-\ell)\pi}2\biggr].
   \end{multline}
   Taking $x\to0$ leads to
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin-eq=0}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(0,-1,0,1,\dotsc, \cos\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\biggl(\cos\frac{n\pi}2\biggr) \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}
   \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n
   \end{multline}
   and
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin=ans=0}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(1,0,-1,0,\dotsc, \sin\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k}{k!2^k} \biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr] \sum_{q=0}^k(-1)^q\binom{k}{q}(2q-k)^n
   =\biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr]2^{n-k}S_{-k/2}(n,k),
   \end{multline}
   where
   \begin{equation*}%\label{S(n,k,x)-satisfy-eq}
   S_r(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}(r+j)^n, \quad n\ge k\ge0.
   \end{equation*}
3. These formulas can be applied to establish general formulas of the $n$th derivatives for functions of the types $f(\sin x)$ and $f(\cos x)$, such as $\sin^\alpha x$, $\cos^\alpha x$, $\sec^\alpha x$, $\csc^\alpha x$, $e^{\pm\sin x}$, $e^{\pm\cos x}$, $\ln\cos x$, $\ln\sin x$, $\ln\sec x$, $\ln\csc x$, $\sin\sin x$, $\cos\sin x$, $\sin\cos x$, $\cos\cos x$, $\tan x$, and $\cot x$.
4. By virtue of some formulas above-mentioned, we have
   \begin{align}
   \frac{\textrm{d}^n\sin^5x}{\textrm{d} x^n}
   &=\sum_{k=0}^n\langle5\rangle_k \sin^{5-k}x B_{n,k}(\cos x, -\sin x, -\cos x,\sin x,\dotsc)\\
   &\to5!B_{n,5}(1, 0, -1,0,\dotsc), \quad x\to0\\
   &=5! \biggl[\cos\frac{(n-5)\pi}2\biggr]2^{n-5}S_{-5/2}(n,5).
   \end{align}
   Consequently, we find
   \begin{equation}
   \sin^5x=5!\sum_{n=0}^\infty\biggl[\cos\frac{(n-5)\pi}2\biggr]\frac{2^{n-5}S_{-5/2}(n,5)}{n!}x^n
   =5!\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{2^{2k}S_{-5/2}(2k+5,5)}{(2k+5)!}x^{2k+5}.
   \end{equation}

References

1. B.-N. Guo, D. Lim, and F. Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Appl. Anal. Discrete Math. **16** (2022), in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
2. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Appl. Math. Comput. **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
3. F. Qi and J. Gelinas, *Revisiting Bouvier's paper on tangent numbers*, Adv. Appl. Math. Sci. **16** (2017), no. 8, 275--281.
4. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *An explicit formula for derivative polynomials of the tangent function*, Acta Univ. Sapientiae Math. **9** (2017), no. 2, 348--359; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/ausm-2017-0026.
5. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Art. 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
6. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
7. F. Qi, G.-S. Wu, and B.-N. Guo, *An alternative proof of a closed formula for central factorial numbers of the second kind*, Turkish J. Anal. Number Theory **7** (2019), no. 2, 56--58; available online at https://doi.org/10.12691/tjant-7-2-5.
8. C.-F. Wei and F. Qi, *Several closed expressions for the Euler numbers*, J. Inequal. Appl. **2015**, Paper No. 219, 8 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1186/s13660-015-0738-9.
9. A.-M. Xu and G.-D. Cen, *Closed formulas for computing higher-order derivatives of functions involving exponential functions*, Appl. Math. Comput. **270** (2015), 136--141; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.08.051.
10. J.-L. Zhao, Q.-M. Luo, B.-N. Guo, and F. Qi, *Remarks on inequalities for the tangent function*, Hacet. J. Math. Stat. **41** (2012), no. 4, 499--506.

Comment: Alternative answers to Maclaurin's series expansions or to the $n$th derivatives of the function $\sin^nx$ can be found in the paper [Yu. A. Brychkov, Power expansions of powers of trigonometric functions and series containing Bernoulli and Euler polynomials, Integral Transforms Spec. Funct. vol. 20 (2009), no. 11-12, 797--804; available online at https://doi.org/10.1080/10652460902867718 ] and in the handbook [A. P. Prudnikov, Yu. A. Brychkov, and O. I. Marichev, Integrals and Series, Elementary Functions,Vol. 1, Gordon and
Breach, NewYork, London, 1986].

Answer (score 2):

For $m,k\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc\}$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{sin-ell-d}
\frac{\textrm{d}^m\sin^kx}{\textrm{d} x^m}
=\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} \sum_{q=0}^k(-1)^q\binom{k}{q}(2q-k)^m \cos\biggl[(m-k)\frac\pi2+(2q-k)x\biggr].
\end{equation}
For $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{sin-poer-exp}
\sin^\ell x=\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell}\sum_{q=0}^\ell(-1)^q\binom{\ell}{q} \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x-\frac{\ell}2\pi\biggr].
\end{equation}
Employing anyone of these two formulas, one can derive Maclarurin's series expansion of the function $\sin^5x$ and, generally, the function $\sin^nx$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

These two formulas can be found in the following paper:

1. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *On the Wallis formula*, International Journal of Analysis and Applications **8** (2015), no. 1, 30--38.

Answer (score 1):

A general answer to this question is the following result.

**Theorem.** For $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{sine-power-ser-expan-eq}
\biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^{\ell}
=1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j}\frac{T(\ell+2j,\ell)}{\binom{\ell+2j}{\ell}} \frac{(2x)^{2j}}{(2j)!},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{T(n-k)-EF-Eq(3.1)}
T(n,k)=\frac1{k!} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\biggl(\frac{k}2-\ell\biggr)^n.
\end{equation}
denotes central factorial numbers of the second kind.

For details of the proof for the above result, please read the arXiv preprint below.

Reference

1. Feng Qi and Peter Taylor, *Several series expansions for real powers and several formulas for partial Bell polynomials of sinc and sinhc functions in terms of central factorial and Stirling numbers of second kind*, arXiv preprint (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612v4 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.