# Power series expansion of $\arctan{\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2+x^2}\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

I'm looking for help with power series expansion (around $x_0=0$, in real domain) of the following function:

$f(x) = x\arctan{\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2+x^2}\right)}$.

Obviously the actual problem is $g(x) = \arctan{\left(\frac{1-x^2}{2+x^2}\right)}$, then $f(x)=xg(x)$ so what we really need is an expansion for $g$. I've already tried the standard approach of differentiating $g$, then expanding the derivative into power series and applying the term-by-term integration theorem, but what I get is $g'(x) = \frac{-6x}{2x^4 +2x^2 +5}$ and I'm having a hard time here trying to expand it into a series.
Of course there's
$\frac{1}{2x^4 +2x^2 +5} = \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{2}{5}x^2(\frac{2x+1}{5})\right)}$, but this leaves me with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{5^{n+1}}\left(x^2(2x^2+1)\right)^n$ and I'm stuck. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I should do is to make $x^2=t$ and to consider
$$f(t)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-t}{2+t}\right)$$ So, as you thought about it, differentiate
$$f'(t)=-\frac{3}{2 t^2+2t+5}$$ Computing the complex roots of the denominator and using partial fraction decomposition
$$f'(t)=\frac{i}{2 \left(t+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3 i}{2}\right)\right)}-\frac{i}{2
   \left(t+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3 i}{2}\right)\right)}$$
$$f'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{i}{2}  \left(-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{3 i}{5}\right)^{n+1} t^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{i}{2}  \left(-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3 i}{5}\right)^{n+1} t^n$$
$$f'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i}{2}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{3 i}{5}\right)^{n+1} -\left(-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{3 i}{5}\right)^{n+1}\right)t^n$$ Using de Moivre, this write
$$f'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} \sin \left((n+1) \left(\pi   -\tan ^{-1}(3)\right)\right) t^n$$ Expanding the sine
$$f'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\right)^{n+1} \sin \left((n+1) \tan ^{-1}(3)\right)\, t^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n$$ Do not worry about the $a_n$'s; they are rational numbers generating the sequence
$$\left\{-\frac{3}{5},\frac{6}{25},\frac{18}{125},-\frac{96}{625},\frac{12}{3125},
   \frac{936}{15625},-\frac{1992}{78125},-\frac{5376}{390625},\frac{30672}{1953125},-
   \frac{7584}{9765625},\cdots\right\}$$ So, integrating termwise
$$f(t)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n+1} t^{n+1}$$
Back to $x$
$$x \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{x^2+2}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n+1} x^{2n+3}=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^{2n+3}$$
The $b_n$'s generate the sequence
$$\left\{-\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{25},\frac{6}{125},-\frac{24}{625},\frac{12}{15625},
  \frac{156}{15625},-\frac{1992}{546875},-\frac{672}{390625},\frac{3408}{1953125}
\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|<\sqrt{2}\,$, we have
\begin{align*}
\arctan\frac{1-x^2}{2+x^2}&=\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{1}{k}\biggl(\frac{3}{2}\biggr)^k \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(-1)^\ell\binom{\ell}{k-\ell-1} \biggl(\frac{4}{5}\biggr)^{\ell+1}\Biggr]x^{2n}.
\end{align*}

References

1. Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, *Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function*, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1.
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4332741/945479.
3. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331451/945479.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge1$, by the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\arctan\frac{1-t}{2+t}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=-3\biggl(\frac{1}{2t^2+2t+5}\biggr)^{(n-1)}\\
&=-3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{(2t^2+2t+5)^{k+1}} B_{n-1,k}\bigl(4t+2,4,0,\dotsc,0\bigr)\\
&=-3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{(2t^2+2t+5)^{k+1}} 4^k B_{n-1,k}\biggl(t+\frac12,1,0,\dotsc,0\biggr)\\
&\to-3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{5^{k+1}} 4^k B_{n-1,k}\biggl(\frac12,1,0,\dotsc,0\biggr), \quad t\to0\\
&=-3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{5^{k+1}} 4^k \frac{1}{2^{n-k-1}}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac1{2^{2k-n+1}}\\
&=-3(n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\frac{2^k}{5^{k+1}} \binom{k}{n-k-1},
\end{align*}
where we used
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we arrive at
\begin{equation*}
\arctan\frac{1-t}{2+t}
=\arctan\frac12+\frac35\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k+1} \biggl(\frac{2}{5}\biggr)^k \binom{k}{n-k-1}\Biggr]\frac{t^n}{n}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\arctan\frac{1-x^2}{2+x^2}
=\arctan\frac12+\frac35\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k+1} \biggl(\frac{2}{5}\biggr)^k \binom{k}{n-k-1}\Biggr]\frac{x^{2n}}{n}.
\end{equation*}

References

1. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.